# Extending polymer's `iron-ajax` without inheritance

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a server that accepts specific headers to allow pagination of query results.
I would like to extend `iron-ajax` so that I can set up the range I want to receive, and know that iron-ajax will set the right headers.

The current way to do this with Polymer is to create an element that includes just an iron-ajax element in its template, and sets every single attribute `iron-ajax` would possibly care about. This is quite labour intensive and fragile. I always find it a little cringy when I see it done within Polymer...

Is there an easy solution to my problem I am totally missing, and doesn't require hard wrapping?

Comment: Native elements can extend Polymer elements like `input` can extend `iron-input`, but custom elements cannot do the same as of yet. As per Polymer's [2016 Roadmap](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/blog/2016-02-17-2016-roadmap.html) extending from custom element is in their plan. Till then i think this is the only option.

Comment: I would like to hear how this works for Polymer 2.0 as well, cannot find any resources.